# Jenkins pipeline: How to run regression test suite and smoke test suite from a single jenkinsfile with two different cron jobs

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, devops

I want to run two builds separately one for regression test suite for every  6 hours and another for smoke test suite for every 4 hours, from a single jenkins file..

We have a current jenkinsfile with parallel() method and triggering corn job for every 6 hours, now that we want to have one more test suite to execute for every 4 hours, how to achieve that.?

Snippet of code is

```
parallel( startParallelTest() )

startParallelTest() {
 def nodeObject [:]
  testTag = tags
 //read environments test, dev and run the test once on each environment
 for (env in environments) {
    nodeObject[env] = { -> node('java180u92-maven333') {
                     stage('Checkout Code') { checkout scm}
                     stage('Compile Code') { sh "mvn clean compile"}
                     triggerTest(env, testTag)
           }

    }

 }

}

def triggerTest(env, testTag) {
 ....
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve this is by using the [Parameterized Scheduler](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-scheduler/) plugin, which allows you to define a crone trigger that will run with a specific value for a specific parameter, that option enables you to have two schedules for the same build - each schedule will run the build with a different parameter value, or in your case a different test suite.

Here is a usage example:

```groovy
pipeline {
   agent any
   parameters {
     string(name: 'PLANET', defaultValue: 'Earth', description: 'Which planet are we on?')
     string(name: 'GREETING', defaultValue: 'Hello', description: 'How shall we greet?')
   }
   triggers {
       parameterizedCron('''
           # leave spaces where you want them around the parameters. They'll be trimmed.
           # we let the build run with the default name
           */2 * * * * %GREETING=Hola;PLANET=Pluto
           */3 * * * * %PLANET=Mars
       ''')
   }
   stages {
       stage('Example') {
           steps {
               echo "${params.GREETING} ${params.PLANET}"
               script { currentBuild.description = "${params.GREETING} ${params.PLANET}" }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

In your case you can use something like the following, trigger once every six hours with a certain value for the test tag, and another schedule for every 4 hours with a different value :

```groovy
properties([
   parameters([
       string(name: 'TEST_TAG', defaultValue: 'test_tag_1', description: 'Test tag to execute'),
   ]),
   pipelineTriggers([
      // one value for every 4 hours, and another value for every 6 hours
      parameterizedCron('''
      0 */6 * * * %TEST_TAG=test_tag_1   
      0 */4 * * * %TEST_TAG=test_tag_2
      ''')
  ])
])

parallel environments.collectEntries { env ->
   ["Running on ${env}": {
       node('java180u92-maven333') {
           stage('Checkout Code') {
               checkout scm
           }
           stage('Compile Code') {
               sh "mvn clean compile"
           }
           triggerTest(env, TEST_TAG)
       }
   }
]}

def triggerTest(env, testTag) {
   ....
}
```

The parameter of the the scheduler can also be a Boolean form which you can then determine the trigger type and run any advance logic you want.

Comment: Is there anyway we can put and condition for env too..?? Say, For test environment, then those two tags (regression and smoke-test) needs to run for 6 hours and 4 hours, where as for prod env, then these two tags needs to run for 2 hours and 1 hour.. In otherwords, based on release branch, want to trigger multiple test builds

Comment: Not sure i understand what you mean, but you can add triggers with multiple parameters, for example ` */2 * * * * TEST_TAG=tests_tag_1;ENV=prd` then add an `if` condition to check environment and run the tests accordingly.